# Detect change in Arduino potentiometer

Tags: arduino

I am trying to write my arduino code to upon detection of a change in the potentiometer analog read value to execute a function.

My question is how do I detect a change in the potentiometer value, I am reading in the potentiometer as normally done, but I am stuck as to how to compare this to see if it has changed.

My loop code for reading potentiometer value:

```
void loop()
{  
  val = analogRead(potpin);
        val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
        Serial.println(val);
        delay(15);
        if (val >= 90)
        {     
          sendSMS5();
          delay(10000);
          switchOff();          
        }

}
```

I am thinking that maybe a number of IF statments to compare if the value falls into a certain bracket is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the value in a variable declared outside the loop.

```
#define TOLERANCE 10

int oldVal = 0;

void loop()
{  
    val = analogRead(potpin);
    val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
    Serial.println(val);
    delay(15);

    int diff = abs(val - oldVal);

    if(diff > TOLERANCE)
    {
        oldVal = val; // only save if the val has changed enough to avoid slowly drifting
        // and so on
    }     

    if (val >= 90)
    {     
        sendSMS5();
        delay(10000);
        switchOff();          
    }

}
```